# Pulling an integer from an index in an array

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is a way in java to pull and integer found at a specific index in an array. I then want to store that integer in a variable. Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
int index = 0;
int value = arr[index];
// value will be 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find an integer found at a specified index in an array. There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Code:

```
**import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindElementInArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n, x, flag = 0, i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the element you want to find:");
        x = s.nextInt();
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == x)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Element found at position:"+(i + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }
    }
}**
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to look over this!

Answer (score 0):

Get the element from `int` array `arr` at index `index` as given below.

```java
int value = arr[index];
```